# Batch rename files to remove suffix after ".csv"

Tags: linux, bash, rename

I want to batch re-name a number of files in a directory so that the shard numbers after .csv are removed:

```
Old file name: XXX.csv-00000-of-00001
New file name: XXX.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `rename` (`prename`), doing dry-run first:

```
rename -n 's/^([^.]+\.csv)-.*/$1/' *.csv*
```

After checking, remove `-n` to let the actual action take place:

```
rename 's/^([^.]+\.csv)-.*/$1/' *.csv*
```

---

Using `bash` parameter expansion:

```
for i in *.csv*; do mv -i "$i" "${i%%-*}"; done
```